# Parse method from string and store it in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to allow users to specify a function for calculating some property and want to store this function in a generic class. That is, each instance of the class have the same interface, but the result of calling the 'calculate' method varies depending on the user supplied function

I would also like to serialize this class and store it in a database for later use. This is what I am thinking

```
class LogicalCharge < Charge
    attr_reader :name, :type, :formula, :threshold

    def initialize(name: nil, type: nil, formula: nil, threshold: nil)
      super(name: name, type: type)
      @formula = formula
      @threshold = threshold
    end

    def parse(formula: nil)

    end

    def calculate(dimensions: nil)
      parse(formula: formula).call(dimensions) < threshold
    end
```

Any advice on how best to proceed from here?

Comment: Executing user-supplied code? Bad, bad idea (from security POV)

Comment: Any advice on another approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach where you have a hierarchy of related classes, one for each of your current variations of the calculate function, and a table with fields for the class name and each of the parameters for running it.

As the classes will all conform to the same interface, this should work well. You can then sanitize the user input cleanly and avoid the horrible security implications of letting users put executable code directly on your server.

Comment: Thing is, I may have 10+ different calculations, would I have to subclass each and everyone?

Comment: @Tarlen How different are they? If the function is complex, with the algorithm depending on the variables, it would make sense to separate into different classes. If it's the same algorithm with different parameters, just have one class and store the params in the DB without the class name.